# /usr/bin Permission change on mac

Tags: macos

I am trying to set up java on XCODE and it needs to access /usr/bin/java at some point. But I cannot get hold of this folder and I get this message:
The folder “java” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.
Even when I try to reach the permission through Get Info the system does not open the folder because of the same restriction. I think it is possible to change the permission through Terminal but I am afraid to blow up something on my mac.
How can I change the permission safely?

Comment: This would probably be better on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK. Thanks. I am transferring it.

Answer (score 0):

As the root user ("sudo su -" from the command line and then enter system password), execute the following from the command line -- "chmod 777 /usr/bin/java" .  That won't blow anything up, and will allow read/write/execute (rwx) to the directory's owner, group, and guests.

-TU